# Getting wrong Image gallery in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-image-gallery

I am new to Bootstrap and want to make a Image gallery. How I expect is

[image]

But I am getting it like this:

[image]

My HTML code is this:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/sell/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="img/slider/slider-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="img/sell/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="img/sell/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                            </a>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Please tell how to write the correct code.

Comment: You are getting it correctly, the only difference is, in your expectation the height of the image on the left is equal to the height of the pictures on the right. It would be better to use sub rows for the right column though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I don't know about sub rows ... can you please tell how to use them.

Comment: Not needed here. But if you intend on splitting the right column into rows, you can have class "row" within "col"s.

Comment: I already tried that but it was again not coming correct. So I changed to it.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Right now it wont be possible. Sorry

Comment: I saw in expected one they are using rowspan. But when I am using it in my page it's not working. Please tell if rowspan can be used and how to use it.

Comment: rowspan applies to table view. If there are 2 rows in a table, and you give rowspan of 2 to a column, that column stretches to 2 rows. It would be better if you can post a simple fiddle and someone can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct code. The difference is, your left image is just not equal is height to the right images.

In the expectation example, the left image is equal to the height of the 2 rows of images on the right. Using a longer image on the right will fix it (or giving the left column more wider column space).